# how to disable keyboard in next activity in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-edittext, search-box

i had problem in keyboard . i made search activity and there i call edit text when i search for anything and by clicking that search the keyboard still activate in another activity . how can i stop it. i tried too much but i need someone help

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.search_activity);
    searchText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Search_Field);
    searchText.addTextChangedListener(this);
    resultView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Display_Result);
    resultView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(SearchActivity.this, web_activity.class);
        intent.putExtra("url", links[position]);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the `android:windowSoftInputMode` parameter in your Manifest?

Comment: Please share your web_activity.java

Answer (score 0):

try that in `onItemClick` before `startActivity`

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

**write this in your web_activity.class onCreate method**

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

**i hope this will work in your case thank you**

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add this to your activity

```
        <activity android:name=".activities.YourSampleActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
        />
```